# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MultiThreading_Start_Stop_Counter.Form1.cancellationTokenSource'

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Can any one help me with the error in this line.

I am trying to build a TPL Multi - Threading application and my intention is to have a start stop button. On click on start the loop will start and like a counter it will display values one by one in the textbox.

and at any point of time if the user clicks on stop button, the task will stop.

Please see the below code for more reference.

Form1.cs:

```
namespace MultiThreading_Start_Stop_Counter
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
                    return;
                }

                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            }
        }, token); 
        task.Start();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

EDIT:
    Form1.cs:

```
namespace MultiThreading_Start_Stop_Counter
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
                    return;
                }

                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            }
        }, token); 
        task.Start();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Now am getting this exception: **An exception of type

> System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**

Comment: Change `CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;` to `CancellationToken token;` and add the following line to the constructor: `token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;`

Comment: Hello @MatthewWatson, I corrected that and now I am getting this exception:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: If you are getting an exception now rather than a compile error, it's a different problem - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the

Comment: @MatthewWatson, hey it is not duplicate

Comment: @mehtaankit It sure is